# Detecting collisions with trajectories

Tags: collision-detection, physics, raycasting, trajectory

What if an object were to have collision detection implemented as so: A ray in the direction the object is moving in, and a ray in the direction of gravity.

Comment: What is your question? Remember, this site is not just a sounding board for ideas. You should phrase a specific question in a specific game development context. Flesh out your proposed algorithm in detail — provide code or pseudo-code — and explain what it is about it that you need help with. If you just want to know if your idea works (for your use case), the best thing you can do is **implement it and test it**. If you want to know if it's a good solution to a particular problem, you need to specify what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Usually objects are not simply points, and by that I mean that usually objects have size. If you only rays to check for collisions, the size of the object is not being taken into account.

Which means that - regardless of how big the object is - it might fall through a crack in floor or similar... How are you representing the floor anyway? You are going to need to define collision shapes one way or another.

*I cannot read your mind, but I'll venture to guess you are trying to find some way avoid tunneling… In which case, I'd suggest to look into how continuous collision detection works.*

Comment: Please forgive me, but you have attempted to answer a non-question.  I have done so many a time, usually answering a one-off duplicate.  Is there a way for you to provide a question to your answer and expand it into a new question and answer?

Comment: @agone I could, but I don't care enough to. You know it reads like a question to me "What if" -> "What would happen if".

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick to use zero sized rays to check collision between two non zero sized objects: You just sum their radiuses. This way when a ray is cast, it will hit larger obstacle, even if it would've missed it at the edge for normal sized obstacle. Only works for a simple shape, sphere. But can be used as a crude first step, and fine details of the collision can be checked later. Or if your physics is simple enough to use spheres as a object's physical model.

Comment: This is related to the notion of [Minkowski addition/differences](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition), which can be applied to more sophisticated collision detection algorithms like GJK.

Comment: wow, thats interesting. didnt expect it has a generalization for other shapes